# Symfony2 - one-to-many template field in forms : don't want to display a select

Tags: forms, symfony, one-to-many

Here is a beginner question for Symfony2.

I have two entities : Article and Comments.

A page displays many articles. Each article can be commented directly from this page.

I created a form for the comment, the problem is that `{{ form_widget(form.article) }}` displays a `<select>...</select>`. I need to "display" a `<input type="hidden" name="article" value="{{ article.id }}"` /> but I don't know how to do.

My best clue is http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field , but i can't make it work.

What would be your solution ? Do you need extra info ?

Thank you

Comment: You'll need a data transformer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: I'd like to give you a valid answer. It worked for me. Do you want to post a "real" answer. Thank you very much.